# Background effect on tap?

Tags: css, mobile, anchor

What is the background effect that appears on tap? In a webpage some `<a>`'s have a visual feedback when tap, but some others don't. On chrome for android it happpens in the form of a blueish background color for a few miliseconds.

Whatever it is, It's similar to :active, but not quite. As it seems not to be defined (as I checked in the inspector) and it only happens on tap (not desktop click).

Is there a way to make every element have it? The inconsistence is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, given not much context, you'd want to reproduce the "ripple" effect. Which is like having some sort of wave of changing color from the position of the click.

I would suggest this tutorial to learn more how the effect is done in plain CSS.

http://www.cssscript.com/android-l-ripple-click-effect-with-javascript-and-css3/

Answer (score 0):

I realized this is just the default styling that happens on the mobile browser for `<a>` elements.

The issue here was that the dimensions of the appearing box weren't matching those of the `<a>` element, but those of its inner (event target?) element.

In other words, in a given `<a><i class="fa fa-icon"></i></a>`. On tap, instead of getting a highlighted `<a>`, I was getting a highlighted `<i>`.